# how to print right using circulardoublylinkedlist

Tags: python, doubly-linked-list

I'm studying data structures in python, and I made `CircularDoublyLinkedList`. There is a problem when I try to print an empty linked list. In that case I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'

In that case I want to print just a blank line. How can I fix this code?

```
class DNode:
    def __init__(self, item, prev = None, next = None):
        self.item = item
        self.prev = prev
        self.next = next

class CircularDoublyLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.head is None

    def clear(self):
        self.head = None

    def addFront(self, item):
        newNode = DNode(item)
        if self.isEmpty():
            self.head = newNode
            self.head.prev = newNode
            self.head.next = newNode

        else:
            newNode.prev = self.head.prev
            newNode.next = self.head
            self.head.prev.next = newNode
            self.head.prev = newNode
            self.head = newNode

    def addRear(self, item):
        newNode = DNode(item)
        if self.isEmpty():
            self.head = newNode
            self.head.prev = newNode
            self.head.next = newNode
        else:
            newNode.prev = self.head.prev
            self.head.prev.next = newNode
            newNode.next = self.head
            self.head.prev = newNode

    def deleteFront(self):
        if not self.isEmpty():
            data = self.head.item
            count = self.size()
            if count == 1:
                self.head = None
            else:
                self.head.next.prev = self.head.prev
                self.head.prev.next = self.head.next
                self.head = self.head.next
            return data

    def deleteRear(self):
        if not self.isEmpty():
            data = self.head.prev.item
            count = self.size()
            if count == 1:
                self.head = None
            else:
                self.head.prev = self.head.prev.prev
                # self.head.prev.prev = self.head.prev
                self.head.prev.next = self.head

                # self.head.next = self.head.next.prev
                # self.head.next = self.head
            return data

    def size(self):
        if self.head is None:
            return 0
        count = 1
        tmp = self.head
        while tmp is not self.head.prev:
            count += 1
            tmp = tmp.next
        return count

    def peekFront(self):
        if not self.isEmpty():
            return self.head.item

    def peekRear(self):
        if not self.isEmpty():
            return self.head.prev.item

    def print(self):
        ptr = self.head.next
        print(self.head.item, end = " ")
        while ptr is not self.head:
            print(ptr.item, end = " ")
            ptr = ptr.next
        print()

    def revPrint(self):
        ptr = self.head.prev
        while ptr is not self.head:
            print(ptr.item, end = " ")
            ptr = ptr.prev
        print(self.head.item)
        print()
def main():
    dq = CircularDoublyLinkedList()
    print("Enter a command: af(addFront), df(deleteFront), pf(peekFront), s(size)")
    print("ar(addRear), dr(deleteRear), pr(peekRear), rp(reversePrint)or q(uit)")

    while True:
        line = input().split()
        command = line[0]
        if command == 'af':
            item = line[1]
            dq.addFront(item)
        elif command == 'df':
            print(dq.deleteFront())
        elif command == 'pf':
            print(dq.peekFront())
        elif command == 'ar':
            item = line[1]
            dq.addRear(item)
        elif command == 'dr':
            print(dq.deleteRear())
        elif command == 'pr':
            print(dq.peekRear())
        elif command == 'p':
            dq.print()
        elif command == 'rp':
            dq.revPrint()
        elif command == 's':
            print("size : ", dq.size())
        elif command == 'q':
            break

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error will occur in the line `ptr = self.head.next`, because `self.head` is `None` and thus has no `.next` attribute.

Solve this by doing the same as you already did in some of the other methods -- check with `isEmpty()`:

```
    def print(self):
        if not self.isEmpty():  # <-- this
            ptr = self.head.next
            print(self.head.item, end = " ")
            while ptr is not self.head:
                print(ptr.item, end = " ")
                ptr = ptr.next
        print()  # ...and this will always execute
```

Comment: thank you so much i was doing like if self.head == None .... 
what a dumb.... thank you so much again and i will study more hard to be like you